# Why gate drive transformer is not connected directly to the gates in this App Note?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, gate-driving

Here’s a circuit from [TI App Note SLUA323](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua323/slua323.pdf), which shows a synchronous rectification in a current doubler circuit.

[image]

U2 is a gate driver.  Transformer T2, which looks very much like a gate drive transformer, provides both signals and power to U2.  The output voltage is only +3.3V, which is a bit low for gate driving.  Transformer provides the gate drive IC with higher voltage.

Obviously, this circuit could be simplified if gates were driven directly by the secondary windings of T2.  What was the rationale behind adding U2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

1. You want to insure that the driving waveform has high enough dV/dt to insure that the transistor is turned on quickly to minimize heating by operating the transistor with lower R<sub>DS(ON)</sub>.
2. You want to insure that the drivers turn on only when there is sufficient voltage being developed.

Comment: UCC37324 does not have under-voltage lockout.

Answer (score 3):

Without digging into the application note itself, I would think that the gate driver U2 and its local power supply are used to get higher current (faster edges) for switching the MOSFETs than you could get from the transformer alone.

This would help with the overall efficiency of the circuit. Note that when either transistor is switched on, it's carrying the full output current (i.e., the current through both inductors).

Answer (score 1):

U2 would be there to snap-up the drive waveforms to the SR FETs.  UCC37324s are pretty hot drivers.

But, more important here is, it is doubtful that the author of the app note ever built this circuit as drawn because it won't work.  Input to the UCC37324 is into a MOS gate, and can't be allowed to float or the output will go high.  The schematic shows no way to pull U2 inputs low after being made high through the diode resistor combo.

Comment: If you have a continuous modulation, and the duty-cycle is constrained to 5%-95%, it would never truly float, and would work finr.